# How to use APIs to view lines in Xtream code 2.9.2?

Tags: php, video-streaming, live-streaming, iptv

How to view Lines from Xtream Code CMS?

I am using some APIs but not able view lines it always shows me 'Access Denied'.
How to allow API access? I have Xtream code 2.9.2 version.
I know To use APIs, we have to import our IP address into the whitelist from General Settings -> API Settings. It was an option in Xtream code 2.3.x but in later versions, they have changed things. And by default, they have disabled the access of APIs. There is no such type of option in the current version of Xtream code we have.
Any solution? How to allow API access in Xtream code 2.9.2?

```
<?php
$panel_url = 'https://cms.xtream-codes.com/xxxx/'; //i am giving my cms xtream code panel link here

$username = "xxxx";  //i am giving my xtream code cms username here
$password = "xxxx";  //i am giving my xtream code cms password here


##############################################################################
$post_data = array( 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password );
$opts = array( 'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query( $post_data ) ) );

$context = stream_context_create( $opts );
$api_result = json_decode( file_get_contents( $panel_url . "api.php?action=user&sub=info", false, $context ), true );
echo  implode( ',', $api_result);
?>
```

Access denied

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the $panel_url refers to the URL to your main server rather than your cms panel

Comment: please provide a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

My solution for checking active subscription info using xtream-codes V2 API
create an Index.php page for your form

```
<form class="form-inline"  action="submit.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter Lines Username" name="username">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Lines Password" name="password">
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">GET STREAM IDS</button>
</form>
```

Create `submit.php` and point your form action to it

```
 <?php
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$exp_date = date("d-m-Y",$json['user_info']["exp_date"]);



$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://<-YOUR DNS ->:<-YOUR PORT ->/panel_api.php?username=$username&password=$password"), true);
?>

<?php echo $json['user_info']["username"];?></a>
<?php echo $json['user_info']["password"];?></a>
<?php echo $json['user_info']["status"];?></a>
<?php echo $exp_date;?></a>

and create a line download button like this
  <a href="http://<-YOUR DNS ->:<-YOUR PORT ->/get.php?username=<?php print $json['user_info']["username"];?>&password=<?php print $json['user_info']["password"];?>&type=m3u_plus&output=ts" class="btn btn-primary">DOWNLOAD PLAYLIST</a>
```

The below code will generate a table of active channels and their TS numbers dependant to the entered line subscription packages

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="50%"><center>STREAM NAME</center></th>
        <th width="50%"><center>STREAM TS NUMBER</center></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://<-YOUR DNS ->:<-YOUR PORT ->/player_api.php?username=$username&password=$password&action=get_live_streams"), true);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($json); $x++)
{ ?>


<td><center><strong><?php echo $json[$x]['name'];?></strong></center></td>

<td><center><strong><?php echo $json[$x]['stream_id'];?></strong></center></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

these may not be the best methods but they work and I actually use myself